# In the context of asymptotic notations, does the equation $\Theta(1) + \Theta(1) = \Theta(1)$ hold?

Tags: algorithms

I know the big theta notation $\Theta(n)$ denotes asymptotically tight

[image]

and $\Theta(1)$ denotes constant time.

From above, I guess the equation

$\Theta(1) + \Theta(1) = \Theta(1) \tag{1}$

hold, since there exist $2c_1, 2c_2$ for the right side make equation hold, is my understanding correct?

and what about the $n \geq n_0$ part?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly, the constants in the two summands need not be equal!
The first summand is bound by the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ and the second is bound by $c'_1$ and $c'_2$, so the result is bound by the constants $c_1+c'_1$ and $c_2+c'_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, what about the $n \geq n_0$ part?

Comment: If $n_0^1,n_0^2$ are the boundary constants for the first and second, respectively, functions in “$\Theta(1)+\Theta(1)$” (remember the notation is a placeholder for some anonymous function) then we can let $n_0:=\max(n_0^1,n_0^2)$ be the boundary constant for the sum. Then that completes the picture, that $\Theta(1)+\Theta(1)=\Theta(1)$ @JJJohn